# Proteins that cannot form biofilm?

Tags: bioinformatics, microbiology, bacteriology, biofilms

I am trying to build a machine learning training set for bacterial protein sequences that form biofilm, and that cannot. I collected the positive sequences from the GO ontology website but for negative sequences I am not sure which sequences to incorporate into my training set.

Can anyone point me to resources for proteins sequences that are known to be not capable of forming biofilms?

Answer (score 2):

**Intracellular proteins cannot form biofilms.** Additionally, many (but not all) extracellular proteins contain an N-terminal cleavable signal sequence.

---

Lory (1992) *Determinants of extracellular protein secretion in **Gram-negative bacteria.*** J Bacteriol 174: 3423-3428.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1592799

Schneewind & Missiakas (2012) *Protein secretion and surface display in **Gram-positive bacteria.*** Philos Trans R Soc Lond B Biol Sci 367:1123-1139.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22411983